# Lost connection to MySQL server while running query in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-error-2013

I'm running a simple query on the MySQL server (5.7.20) inside Docker container.
Query is run from a BASH script inside the same container. Variables are exported and defined. Credentials are checked and valid.

`mysql --user="root" --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" --show-warnings --verbose -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${MYSQL_TEST_DB};"`

There is no firewall problem since the MySQL server is binned to 127.0.0.1. Running and connecting also from localhost.
/etc/hosts does have a `127.0.0.1 localhost` defined.

Service is running and I'm able to login to MySQL over CLI with the same credentials.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Full error message shows

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading
>   initial communication packet', system error: 104

Not finding anything useful on Google or SO and running out of ideas.
Most of the answers are connected to firewall or timeout answers.

Comment: What if you try to specify `0.0.0.0` as host in your command line? (ie adding `-h 0.0.0.0` switch) ?

Comment: I can run the same command from the CLI and it works (and from the script), but randomly and first time after the container is up, it fails with the above mentioned error. MySQL server works all the time, without any hiccups and I can see the process. I'm checking if the process is up before running the commands. Al of this is run from the container from the 127.0.0.1 host

Comment: Your `mysql` container may be `Up`, but that does not mean the `MySQL server` is ready to handle connections. I ran into the same problem with a `PostgreSQL` dockerized service. Take a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I'm running the MySQL server under supervisor. Maybe I'll found something for supervisor config, for supervisord to be depended by child processes it starts,

Comment: Still not able to connect...On container up, I'm testing for the MySQL process to be up in a loop with sleep before proceeding with the next step. It goes up after 6-7 seconds. In the next step, I'm doing the test again until the process is up for sure. Then I'm doing a test login which fails with `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104`, thenagain which fails with `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`, then a test to connect over socket not TCP protocol. Still failing..

Comment: All of this is done by a gitlab-runner, maybe that's the problem? But running as the same user which runs the runner I'm able to exec to the same container and execute all MySQL commands successfully. Even at the same time while the runners pipeline is failing.. All querys are executed from inside the docker on it's mysql server. So not a firewall problem, nor with the timeout or bind settings

Comment: Indeed maybe `gitlab-runner` has a system-specific config which fails on this step. From what you describe, I can't see any other explanation for this weird behavior...